# Breakpoints multiply as the independent variable shifts by a constant

Tags: r, breakpoints

I'd like to identify breakpoints in a data set. I don't know how many there will be beforehand or where they might occur. Here's an example with a single breakpoint at `x = 11`.

```r
# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20,  y = c(1:10, 5 * (11:20) - 4 * 11))

# Examine data
plot(df, pch = 19, cex = 2)
abline(v = 11, lty = "dashed", cex = 1.5, col = "gray50")
```

[image]

I look for breakpoints using `strucchange::breakpoints`.

```r
# Look for breakpoints
bp <- strucchange::breakpoints(y ~ x, data = df)

# Label regions in data frame
df$partition <- cut(1:nrow(df), breaks = c(1, bp$breakpoints, nrow(df)), include.lowest = TRUE)

# Examine breaks
with(df, plot(x, y, col = partition, pch = 19, cex = 2))
abline(v = 11, lty = "dashed", cex = 1.5, col = "gray50")
```

[image]

Two are identified, but pretty close together. Okay, I can live with that, as it at least gives me the ballpark. But the weird part is when I simply shift `x` by a constant amount, +50.

```r
# Shift x-axis
df$x <- df$x + 50

# Look for breakpoints
bp <- strucchange::breakpoints(y ~ x, data = df)

# Label regions in data frame
df$partition <- cut(1:nrow(df), breaks = c(1, bp$breakpoints, nrow(df)), include.lowest = TRUE)

# Examine breaks
with(df, plot(x, y, col = partition, pch = 19, cex = 2))
abline(v = 61, lty = "dashed", cex = 1.5, col = "gray50")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now, the function identifies **4** breakpoints, but the underlying structure of the data hasn't changed besides the shift. Why do these spurious breakpoints occur and can I prevent the problem (e.g., by processing the data beforehand, such as normalisation)?

Comment: I'm not an expert nor do I know the end result, but if it helps since you shifted `x`, if you as well shift `y` by the same amount `df$y <- df$y + 50`, then you'll have a similar **2** break points.

Comment: @deepseefan Hah. Interesting. I was curious if the relative scales of `x` and `y` mattered, which is why I mentioned normalisation (although normalisation doesn't actually help).

Comment: Intuitively it seems one is dependent on the other, but again it all depends on your particular case.